# How to make a website responsive over screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My question might have been answered several times before. But, none of them has so far cleared some of my doubts that I have mentioned forward:

Consider that I have a webpage, that shows three rows when the screen-size is more than 700px:

```
<table id='table_1'>
       <tr>
           <td>Apple</td>
           <td>Pineapple</td>
           <td>Palm</td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Now, when my screen-size is less than 700px, three rows create each of the rows a bit shorter and less wider, for which I intended to create a table with three columns instead with the same content in each of the rows, that lead to:

```
<table id='table_2'>
       <tr><td>Apple</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Pineapple</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Palm</td></tr>
</table>
```

So, what I next did is, I added some jQuery script to my file as this:

```
var w = $(window).width();
if(w<700){
        
document.getElementById('table_1').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('table_2').style.display='block';
}

else {

        document.getElementById('table_1').style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('table_2').style.display='block';
        
}
```

But, surprisingly, it didn't work. Later, I moved to CSS media queries, which lead to:

```
@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
#footer1{display:'none';}
#footer2{display:'block';}
}
```

What actually happens is:
When I open my site in a browser, if the browser window at that time has a width more than 700px, it shows `table_1`. But later on, when it is customized by me, dragging the window and creating a smaller one with a width much less than 600px, the same table is still in display, whereas `table_2` was supposed to be shown. But, that does not seem responsive at all to me. What's wrong?

Edit: I removed the function `checkstatus()` as everyone was saying. Moreover, I added these code snippet in my script tag of the main document. Any further edit or help would be appreciated.

Comment: your js method `checkstatus()` is unnecessary, With only css you can do it

Comment: When you were saying "...three rows when the screen-size is more than 700px:" - Actually, those are columns in a single row. `<tr>` is table row and `<td>` is table column.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
#footer1{display: none;}
#footer2{display: block;}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #footer1{display: block;}
    #footer2{display: none;}
}
```

One thing you're missing is that, table for `display: block` is not suit. `display: table`  would be right

Comment: That won’t work. The CSS is littered with syntax errors.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry, I've only copied OP's code, I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve web pages responsive by using css media queries only. Here you don't have to use javascript code to achieve this.

Try to add below css code to your project and see. Don't forget to put meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <style>
      #table_2
      {
        display:none;
      }     
      @media (max-width:700px)
      {
         #table_1
          {
            display:none;
          }
          #table_2
          {
            display:block;
          }
      }
      @media (min-width:701px) and   (max-width:1400px)
      {
         #table_1
          {
            display:block;
          }
          #table_2
          {
            display:none;
          }
      }
</style>
```

/*
You may also use below screen sizes as per your requirement like

// X-Small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// X-Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

// XX-Large devices (larger desktops, 1400px and up)
@media (min-width: 1400px) { ... }

*/